# symfony запуск миграций после установки бандла

Tags: php, symfony, миграция, doctrine, symfony4

Я пытаюсь создать свой bundle для symfony 4.4 и в нем есть свои таблицы, с которыми он работает.
Можно ли как-то создать doctrine миграции которые будут относиться непосредственно к бандлу и при установке бандла запустить их автоматически?
Если да, то буду благодарен за подсказку.

Comment: Такое вряд ли будет выгодно для конечного пользователя. Лучше будет дать инструкцию чтобы он прописал [пути миграций](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) у себя в проекте и запустил. Миграции как таковые должны управляться отдельно, вручную, а не автоматически.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov прав. Сама суть бандла заключается в автономности своей работы и гибкости настройки под нужды пользователя. Автоматически делать запуск каких либо ни было процессов достаточно опрометчиво.

Comment: Однако что касается запуска автоматически чего то, то посмотрите в сторону postinstallscripts каких нибудь в composer.json.   Однако я не уверен что бандлу будет позволительно что то похожее делать.

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю

Answer (score 0):

Автоматически - нет.

Если у вас в бандле присутствуют классы с аннотацией `@ORM\Entity` или указанные в конфиге бандла, то после установки бандла просто запустите

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

создадутся миграции создания таблиц для вашего бандла
примените миграции

после удаления бандла снова запустите

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

создадутся миграции удаления таблиц вашего бандла.

Такой путь является наиболее корректным, поскольку пользователь может оценить миграции перед применением, исправить конфликты и т.д. А при "автомате" возможны деструктивные изменения